# Interacting with Word via .NET

Tags: .net, matlab, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

*After a few more minutes of experimenting, I answered my own question (see below). I'll accept that answer when SO lets me in 2 days.*

---

I am using MATLAB's .NET functionality to create a Word document. I'd like to create a table and merge the top two cells in the lefthand column. So far I can create the table:

```
NET.addAssembly('microsoft.office.interop.word');         %# Register Word assembly
wordApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass; %# Create an instance of Word
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents;                              %# Get the object that handles documents
newDoc = wordDoc.Add;                                     %# Add a new document
wordApp.Visible = 1;                                      %# Make Word visible
selection = wordApp.Selection;                            %# Get the selection object to manage selected area
table = newDoc.Tables.Add(selection.Range, 3, 5);         %# Create a table
table.Style = 'Table Grid';                               %# Add grid lines
```

I'm having trouble calling the `selection.MoveDown` method. Running [METHODSVIEW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/methodsview.html) on this method indicates the following input parameters:

- Microsoft.Office.Word.Selection this
- System.Object Unit
- System.Object Count
- System.Object Extend

The [Selection.MoveDown documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.movedown.aspx) suggests that the Unit parameter is a WdUnits enumeration which I found in MATLAB at `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCell`.

My problem is that I can't find the WdMovementType enumeration needed by the Extend parameter. I want to use the wdExtend value but I can't find it. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdmovementtype%28v=office.14%29.aspx) it should be at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType. **Can anyone tell me where to find wdExtend?**

**EDIT**

WdMovementType does in fact live where it's supposed to, i.e. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType. Now I'm getting an error when trying to run the MoveDown method:

```
>> selection.MoveDown(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCell, 1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType.wdExtend);
??? Message: Bad parameter
Source: Microsoft Word
HelpLink: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\WDMAIN11.CHM#36888
```

Any idea how to call this method properly?

**EDIT**

The call to MoveDown should use the `wdLine` value for the units:

```
>> selection.MoveDown(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine, 1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType.wdExtend);
```

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you running?

Comment: And what is the exact syntax you are using to call MoveDown, and the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @Andrew Janke - I'm using R2011a. I added the MoveDown syntax I'm using and the resulting error message in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following to check the enumerations in the Word assembly:

```
>> word = NET.addAssembly('microsoft.office.interop.word');
>> word.Enums
```

The results included:

```
 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType'
```

so I thought I'd try accessing it even though it wasn't appearing in MATLAB's tab completion. Strangely enough, after accessing it once it now appears! I guess it was there all along.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download the latest one assembly for the Word 2010.
You can download them from [microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)
[How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the Word assembly (see the first line of the code example in the question). The problem is that I cannot find the WdMovementType enumeration within it. Do I need a different assembly?

Comment: What version of assembly do you have? I suggest you to download the latest one for the Word 2010.